# Read a hex string from a file in python

Tags: python

I want to read this hex string from a file in python

0xd3b2178c
Is it possible to read a hex string from a file?

I thought opening the file as "rb" would make python not treat everything as a string, but it does not seem to be the case.

Having read it as a string, is it possible to convert it to hex without changing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into an `int` just fine, if that's what you want to do:

```
>>> int('0xd3b2178c', 16)
3551664012
```

You don't need to open the file in binary mode for this.

Comment: Thanks but I am  picking bits of the hex string and encoding them, so I do not want to convert the whole string into int.

Comment: @Illusionist What do you need to do then?

Comment: Pick some bits and then do bit shift operations / add and then convert to int. But I just realized I can just pick the bits and convert them individually to int, and do my operations.. thanks!!